# Add javascript to Webview

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have created a `javascript` script and would like to run it in a `webview` in my `android` app. How do I go about doing this so when the user clicks on the money `button` the `javascript` runs.

#### Code Below

#### Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.leaddyno.com/js"></script>
<script>
  LeadDyno.key = "hg5kjh5j4h6jhjhjkk7hjhjhjkh56vhjfgcg4gjd";
  LeadDyno.recordVisit();
  LeadDyno.autoWatch();
</script>
```

#### Button Click

```
btnMoney.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //Run Javascript
          myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:LeadDyno.recordVisit()");
          myWebview2.loadUrl("javascript.LeadDyno.autoWatch()");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create assets folder in app/src/main;
2. create a new file html.html;
3. add your javascript code into html.html;
4. load it by webview like:

   webview.load("file:///android_asset/html.html");
5. Do not forget to add android.permission.INTERNET in your manifest file